# Priority queue and Prim's Algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

I have gone through the C++ reference manual and am still unclear on how to use the priorityqueue data structure in STL.

So, basically I have been trying to implement my own using heaps.

I am doing this for implementing Prim's algorithm.

```
Vector <int, int> pq;
```

This is my priority queue. The first field is the node and the second field the weight to the existing tree.

I plan to modify the values of weight in pq every time a new node is added to the tree by updating the weights of its neighbour nodes.

- How do I access the individual elements of this vector? I also need to be able to delete elements at will.

Is this a good way to implement a priority queue? what if I want to add another field to the container, namely

```
Vector<int, int, int> MST
```

- How would I access the third element? I want to store the resulting MST this way such that the first two fields represent the vertices forming the edge, and the third the weight.

It would also help if someone could tell me how to assign elements to this vector using push_back.

- Also, would the conventional C++ STL priority queue help in this as I need to update the priority values each time a new element is added to the MST? Would it self-correct itself according to the priority when values are modified?
- One other question, these Vectors, when I pass them to a function, and try to make changes, is it a pass by value or pass by reference - Or, are the changes reflected outside the function?

Comment: Are you referring to the ancient and outdated ARM with "the C++ reference manual"?

Comment: If you mean `std::vector` as `Vector`, STL vector could have only one template parameter for element type (in fact it also has allocator template parameter). You can use `std::vector<std::pair<int,int>>` for your purposes instead. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/

Comment: @PlasmaHH : I actually meant the cplusplus.com site as reference. I thought that was legit :)

Comment: @vard: Yes. I mean std::vector. Well, I need to add both the edges and the weight and be able to access the elements individually to print.

Comment: @Floose in fact you want to have indexed priority queue, am I right?

Comment: @vard: Sorry, not indexed. Just the way I mentioned for the priority queue. I need to move elements around, So no point indexing it.

Comment: @Floose: cplusplus.com is in no way affiliated with the c++ programming language (as defined by ISO 14882:2011(e)). It is even considered to be not a good site to learn C++, and as a reference, many people prefer cppreference.com

Comment: @PlasmaHH : Alright. Sometimes, I find the syntax very hard to follow.

Comment: @vard: Ah sorry, I made changes to my comment without telling you. I am not sure how Iwould use an indexed pq in this situation. I just need a way to access the elements and I should be good to go. I am implementing it as a heap

Comment: @Floose When you want to update some node neighborous - maybe you know their indexes, it depends on your graph representation don't you? If yes, then you can use their indexes as indexes in PQ and update it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Prim's algorithm the random access to elements not needed. You just need to skip elements from the queue which connect already connected and pass forward.

So the algorithm looks as follows:

1. choose a node `N`
2. add all edges from `N` to the PQ
3. pop a minimal cost edge from PQ

   - if it connects nodes which are already in the tree, skip it
   - otherwise add this edge to the tree, call the new node `N` and go back to point 2.

After adding the node just check if size of the tree is already `size of graph - 1`. If so then finish.

Note that the only operations on PQ are `add_element` and `pop_minimum` - thus `std::priority_queue` will work.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean and how I should do it. I thought a priority queue is the easiest implementation

Comment: I didn't write it clearly. I meant that the random access is not needed. I will update the answer

Comment: Ah okay. I was not asking about random access. Just how to store elements and retrieve in Vector <int, int>

Comment: Then it seems I misunderstood, sorry. I will check it again.

Comment: I am having a little trouble realizing this part in code- "pop a minimal cost edge from PQ- if it connects nodes which are already in the tree, skip it" How do I check this? It would also help if you could include in your answer how the STL priority queue works- I could not comprehend the syntax at all.

Comment: Also every time, the queue needs to be updated and the queue needs to be sorted again- does the STL implementation allow that?

Comment: Yes, semantics of the priority queue guarantee that you get a minimal element on pop. It is not necessarily sorted but this is not important - you only need a `pop_minimum` operation.

Comment: Concerning skipping you need to keep track of added vertices. Just keep a `bool done[]` array saying if a vertex is already in the tree. If both ends of a given edge are in the tree than you skip.

Comment: Concerning the `priority_queue` from the STL you can just check http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/priority_queue/ . There are both needed operation `push` new element and `pop` minimal one. Just create a structure for edges and create a `priority_queue` of edges.

Comment: When choosing the smallest edge value from the priority queue how do I know which vertices it connects?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, `std::vector<int,int>` isn't valid - the second type argument is an (optional) allocator, and int is not an allocator. If you're using a different underlying container, please say what it is. I'll assume you want to work with `std::vector` for now.

Secondly, `std::priority_queue` doesn't support the operations you want (access and delete arbitrary elements), so you can't use that.

You can use the underlying vector directly, and the heap algorithms (`std::make_heap` etc.) to sort it:

- random access will work (although it's not clear what you expect the index to be once your vector is in heap order)
- deleting an arbitrary element will require erasing it from the vector and re-running make_heap, or you can implement your own *siftDown*

Oh, and you can make some value type to store in your vector, such as

```
std::vector<std::pair<int,int>>
```

for your first example, or perhaps more clearly:

```
struct {
  int node;
  int weight;
} Node;
// ...
std::vector<Node>
```

Comment: How would I access indidvidual elements of vector<Node> ? I also do not understand what an allocator does and why this would make the implementation valid.

Comment: @Floose You can use `std::vector` at() method, or random access operator, also you can use iterators and raw pointer to access vector elements.

Comment: No, as in do I use the same vector[i].node and vector[i].weight? Is this correct ?

Comment: @Floose Yes it is correct, but it may be better to use at() operator, because it checks vector bounds itself, while operator[] doesn't.